# как развернуть 3 react проекта на одном vds с помощью nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, vps, vds

сделал 3 одинаковые react app через vite, все работают на разных портах (на одинаковых тоже пребывал не помогло) проекты максимально простые с count++, размещаю на облако конфиг default.conf nginx следующий (крутил уже по всякому):

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name _;

location / {
    root /var/www/app1/dist/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /app2/ {
    alias /var/www/app2/dist/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app2/index.html;
}

location /app3/ {
    alias /var/www/app3/dist/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app3/index.html;
}
```

}
Проблема: первое приложение по пути / работает, во всех остальных грузиться html, но приложение не работает - отдает пустую страницу [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Как сделать что-бы работали все 3 ?

Comment: Поддомены вам надо

Comment: Так надо в самих приложениях корневой путь настроить...